# kafka kafkaServer.out how to rotate this log?

Tags: apache-kafka

I cannot find settings for this log file kafkaServer.out in log4j.properties. Do you have any idea where is configuration for this log in case of MaxFileSize, etc?

Comment: There is no `.out` file, by default. Please describe how you are running Kafka

Comment: Kafka is started from RHEL7 service

Comment: Kafka doesn't come with a service file. Please share it. This is likely what creates the out file

Comment: OK, I understand. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log contains the kafkaServer.out file, which is easy to reproduce. Execute kafka-server-start.sh with the -daemon parameter.

eg:
**./kafka-server-start.sh -daemon  ../config/server.properties**

If you do not want the kafkaServer.out file to appear,use the following command：
**nohup ./kafka-server-start.sh ../config/server.properties  > /dev/null 2>&1 &**

Of course, in the case of kafka on docker/k8s, the **-daemon** and **nohup** parameters are often not used, so it is not necessary to exist.